# codeigniter associative array in post

Tags: codeigniter, webforms

I normally name my db specific fields in my forms like this "objectname[columnname]", I tseems CI cant access these values using $this->input->post('objectname[columnname]'), what do I do? there is not a chance in hell im renaming 100+ form fields.. I am actually disliking CI, it really is getting in the way of progress by changing the de facto PHP norms...

Comment: What version of CI are you running? POST arrays have been supported since 1.7 http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/89251/

Comment: may be she is using 1.7 verson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this post whilst looking for a similar issue, but worked out a CI way to do it, sorry if I'm resurrecting it, but it does appear fairly high on the Google results.

```
// Load the 'array' helper
$this->load->helper('array');
// Use the 'element' function to return an element from the array
echo element('ColumnName', $this->input->post('ObjectName'));
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes here in future.

Answer (score 11):

And were you using `$_POST['objectname[columnname]']` or `$_POST['objectname']['columnname']` ?

Have you tried the equivalent for the latter

```
$obj = $this->input->post('objectname');
echo $obj['columnname'];
```

?

If it works, you can write you own helper to retreive that like `post_val('objectname[columnname]')`.

Comment: no problem. if it solves your problem, could you accept the answer ? so that anybody coming later with the same problem sees it ?

Comment: Writing a helper function would be the cleanest way I see, apart from modifying CI.

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="myPostArrayName[]">
<input type="text" value="" name="myPostArrayName[]">
```

Handling form with codeigniter:

```
$data = $this->input->post('myPostArrayName', TRUE);
```

You can access data in order like this

```
echo 'Value of the first element in the form array is '.$data[0];
echo 'Value of the second element in the form array is '.$data[1];
```

I think someone who has access to codeigniter documentation, had better to add a simple html post array handling example.

Answer (score 0):

I seems I can rely on the $_POST var, but I thought this was reset?

Comment: CI destroys the $_GET variable, not $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the post array as an object and use method chaining to return sub-arrays (now properties) using PHP 5.3's method chaining all on one line.

Extend the input class by making a class called MY_Input and put the extended class in the application/core folder. CI 2.0 will automatically use the extended class with the MY_ prefix, and you can add methods to this new class.  Extending the input class is cleaner than making helpers.

This method casts the post array, or a nested array (a sub array below the parent), as an object.

```
/* Cast an array from CI post as an object and return the object */
public function post_obj($key = null){
  $post_return = $this->post($key);
  if (false === $post_return)
    return false;
  return (object)$post_return;
}
```

Now I can retrieve nested values in one line of code using PHP 5.3's method chaining for objects.

```
$active = $this->input->post_obj('user')->active;
```

Answer (score -6):

I just went with the $_POST['objectname']['colname'] option as i usually do even though this is probably not the CI way..

Comment: It does work but its not the CI way and avoids all sorts of things like global XSS cleaning.